# Dudas con los ArraysList y LinkedList

Tags: java

En el siguiente ejercicio, ¿cómo resuelvo los dos puntos destacados en negrita?:

Opción 1: Insertar una persona

Se debe crear un objeto Persona (solicitando su nombre **y edad** por teclado) y añadirlo a la lista. **(no entiendo como añadir también la edad).**

Opción 2: Borrar una persona indicando su posición

Mediante esta opción se solicita al usuario una posición de la lista y se elimina la persona que ocupe dicha posición. Si la lista está vacía se mostrará el mensaje: “No se pueden eliminar elementos. La lista está vacía.”

Si el usuario indica una posición no válida de la lista (una posición negativa o **fuera del índice válido de la lista**) se mostrará el mensaje: "Posición no válida."**(lo he intentado pero no me funciona).**

Opción 3: Borrar personas indicando su nombre

Se solicita al usuario un nombre por teclado y se elimina de la lista aquellas personas cuyo nombre sea el indicado.

Si la lista está vacía se mostrará el mensaje: “No se pueden eliminar elementos. La lista está vacía.”

Se mostrará un mensaje **indicando el número de personas eliminadas**: “Se han eliminado 4 personas.”**(creo que aquí tendría que usar algún contador).**

Este es el main:

```
java

package Practica;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListaPersonas {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);

       Persona persona = new Persona();

       int op;
       boolean salir=false;



       while(salir == false){
           System.out.println("\n1.Insertar una persona "
                   + "\n2.Borrar una persona indicando posicion."  
                   + "\n3.Borrar una  persona indicando nombre "
                   + "\n4.Mostrar todas las personas(Ordenas por nombre)"
                   + "\n5.Modificar una persona por posicion"
                   + "\n6.Borrar toda la lista "
                   + "\n7.Salir");

           op = leer.nextInt();

           switch(op){
               case 1: persona.Insertar();
              System.out.println("Persona añadida");
                   break;
               case 2: persona.BorrarPorPosicion();
                   break;
               case 3: persona.BorrarPorNombre();
                   break;
               case 4: persona.Mostrar();
                   break;
               case 5: persona.ModificarPorPosicion();
                   break;
               case 6: persona.Borrar();
                   break;
               case 7: salir=true;
                   System.out.println("Ha salido");
                   break;


           }
        }
    }

}
```

Esta es la clase:

```
package Practica;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Persona {
private String nombre;
private int edad;

LinkedList lista=new LinkedList();

public Persona(){

}

public Persona(String nombre, int edad){
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.edad=edad;
}
    /**
     * @return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @return the edad
     */
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    /**
     * @param edad the edad to set
     */
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public void Insertar(){
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre");
        String persona = teclado.nextLine();
        lista.add(persona);

    }

    public void BorrarPorPosicion(){
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
       if(lista.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("No se pueden eliminar elementos. La lista está vacía.");
        }else{
        System.out.println("Indique la posicion para borrar");
        int pos=teclado.nextInt();
        if(pos<0){
            System.out.println("Valor no valido");
        if(pos>lista.size()){
            System.out.println("Posicion no valida");
        }else{
        lista.remove(pos);

                }
            } 
       }
    }

    public void BorrarPorNombre(){
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
        if(lista.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("No se pueden eliminar elementos, la lista esta vacia");
        }else{
        System.out.println("Indique el nombre para borrar");
        String nom=teclado.nextLine();
        lista.remove(nom);
        }
    }

    public void Mostrar(){
        Collections.sort(lista);
        System.out.println(lista.size());
        Iterator it = lista.iterator();
                      while (it.hasNext()){
                           System.out.println(it.next()+"");
                       }

    }

    public void ModificarPorPosicion(){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(lista.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("No se pueden eliminar elementos, la lista esta vacia");
        }else{
        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del elemento para modificar");
        int pos=teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo elemento");
        String elem=leer.nextLine();
        lista.set(pos, elem);
        }
    }

    public void Borrar(){
        lista.clear();
        System.out.println("Se ha borrado la lista");
    }



}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que @Tiberius te ha explicado las diferentes dudas planteadas. Yo solamente tengo una crítica que hacer a tu clase `Persona`, porque veo que has puesto dentro de ella una propiedad: `LinkedList lista=new LinkedList();` Hacer eso es tan absurdo como decir que: *cuando alguien nace nace con una `lista` o va a recibir sí o sí una `lista`*. Quiero decir con esto que cuando diseñas las clases debes pensar que esa clase debería tener solamente los atributos que le son propios. Una lista de personas es algo que necesitarás sin duda en otra parte del programa, no **dentro** de la clase `Persona`

Comment: Lo mismo pasa con todos los métodos que tienes dentro de `Persona`... es como si has querido meter en la clase `Persona` toda la lógica del programa. Eso se nota por ejemplo en que en cada método creas una instancia de `Scanner`. Tendrías que trabajar con una sola instancia de `Scanner` e ir llamando los métodos que necesites en cada momento. Muchos de esos métodos (todos los que no sean **exclusivos** de `Persona`) deben ir en otra parte. Imagina que luego hay que trabajar con vehiculos, ¿duplicarás cada método también en la clase `Vehiculo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea la lista implementando `List`, e indicandole el tipo `persona` que es lo que le vas a meter, la edad es una propiedad del objeto persona, ya la estas metiendo cada vez que metes una persona a la lista.

```
List<Persona> listalinked = new LinkedList<Persona>();
```

Antes de añadirlo a la lista tienes que agregar las propiedades del objeto o bien con el constructor por defecto o añadiéndolas después.

```
persona.setNombre(leer.next());
persona.setEdad(leer.nextInt());
```

Se te ha olvidado cerrar el if al borrar por posición.

```
public void BorrarPorPosicion(){
       Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
       if(lista.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("No se pueden eliminar elementos. La lista está vacía.");
        }else{
           System.out.println("Indique la posicion para borrar");
           int pos=teclado.nextInt();
           if(pos<0){
               System.out.println("Valor no valido");
           }                                         //Este if hay que cerrarlo
           if(pos>lista.size()){
               System.out.println("Posicion no valida");
           }else{
              lista.remove(pos);
           }
        } 
       }
    }
```

Para mostrar las personas eliminadas simplemente comparas antes y después de eliminar el tamaño de la lista.